# Is it possible to link to a configurable product with pre-selected values?

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

I'm building a couple fairly large configurable products under the Products category with about 175 products that basically have the same content, just different options (& they need their own SKU's). Unfortunately those products also show up under their respective Brands sub-categories.

Here's my question...

Is it possible to link to the configurable product & have an option selected depending on where they came from?

For example, if I have them coming from the Nike brand category, is it possible to have those options selected already on the configurable product so they don't have to select it again? I know it's possible to have options pre-selected from the configurable product backend side, but there's multiple ways people get to this page...and I would like them to have the options selected appropriate to where they came from.

(ie - if they went to Nike > Atheletic Wear > Hoodies...they would click on Hoodies, which would lead them to the configurable product page where 'Nike' under the 'Brands' would be selected and so on & so forth)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a full answer but could be a nudge in the right direction.
You can autoselect configurable product options using an url hash.
Take a look for example here:

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/new-arrivals/linen-blazer.html#92=22&180=77

If you add `#attribute_id=value_id` to the URL Magento will select automatically the options you specify.
Now all you need to do is to find a way to append to the URL of the configurable products these values depending on the page you are on.
If you have only the brand as a configurable attribute then it should be easy.
You already know the id of of the brand attribute.
And for the value just create a new attribute for categories, with a custom source model that returns as options all the brands.
Let's call it `brand`.
Select for each category the brand you want autoselected.
Then in the product list page add something like this:

```
$urlSuffix = '';
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    $urlSuffix = '#'.'brand attr id here'.'='.Mage::registry('current_category')->getBrand(); //find a way so you don't hard code the brand attribute id.
}
```

Then replace all occurrences of

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getUrl()?>">...</a>
```

with

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getUrl().$urlSuffix;?>">...</a>
```

If you have more attributes that need to be autoselected I think you can do the same as for brand attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the labels or codes rather than ids?

Comment: @NotJay. Not that I know of.

Comment: Suppose I have the attribute code shirt_size and I can get the value of it when looping through the products like `$subproduct->getAttributeText('shirt_size');` --- in this case how can I easily get the  `#attribute_id=value_id` as per your example? Mabe we can add this to the answer ... super thanks!

Comment: You can get the value using `$subproduct->getShirtSize()` and the attribute id with `Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'shirt_size')->getId()`

Comment: how can i do it for product listing page instead of product details page

Comment: Anything like this for Magento 2?

Comment: @thaddeusmt did you find something?