# Link to configurable product with specific values selected

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Similar to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25540/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-configurable-product-with-pre-selected-values), but with Magento 2

I want to load a configurable product page, with pre-selected attribute value.

My final purpose is to replace the simple product's url in the catalog with the "parent" configurable's url, with the selected attribute values from the simple product.

I have retrieved the "parent" configurable's url for every product, and i have replaced it with the simple product's url in the catalog. I am missing a way to load the configurable's product page, with different selected values each time.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted my answer from this [code snippet here](https://daan.dev/how-to/redirect-simple-products-configurable-parent-attributes-pre-selected/)...

This method will take a configured product and a simple child product and return the "hash" URL that preselects the variant. The key method doing the work here is `getConfigurableAttributesAsArray()`

```
 /**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $parentProduct
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $simpleProduct
 * @return string Hashed Url
 */
public function getHashUrl($parentProduct, $simpleProduct)
{
    $configType = $parentProduct->getTypeInstance();
    $attributes = $configType->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($parentProduct);
    $options = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $id = $attribute['attribute_id'];
        $value = $simpleProduct->getData($attribute['attribute_code']);
        $options[$id] = $value;
    }
    $options = http_build_query($options);
    return $parentProduct->getProductUrl().($options ? '#' . $options : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To preselect a simple product in a configurable product, the address of a simple product should look like this for example:

> `/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html#143=167&93=53`

where

`/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html` - configurable product URL,

`143`, `93` - attributes IDs,

`167`, `53` - option IDs.

In order to change the URL of simple products, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getProductUrl()`, where to generate the URL as in the example above.

---

I made `VCT Simple Product URL` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem.